# Is it possible to insert an HTML tag from pseudo-element content using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the pseudo-element `::before` to insert an `<hr>` before each `<article>` tag, so far I have:

```
  article::before {
    content: "\003C br \\ \003E";
  }
```

but this doesn't work.  Is there some other way of inserting HTML tags into pseudo-element CSS?

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said by @rounin you can't insert html in the generated content.

But `hr` is just an element with its custom CSS styling.

You can recreate the styling for your generated content

```css
article::before {
  content: "";
  border: 1px inset;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: gray;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
```

```html
<article>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque nihil odit impedit ipsam et ducimus.</article>
<article>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim deleniti!
</article>
```

Comment: Perfect that replicates the <hr> tag exactly, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't insert HTML markup into the `content:` attribute of the `::before` pseudo-element - the CSS spec won't allow it.

However, you *can* simulate an `<hr>` before the contents of your article (if that's what you need) simply by declaring `margin-top:` followed by `border-top:` followed by `padding-top:`

```css
article {
  margin-top: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque nihil odit impedit ipsam et ducimus.</article>
<article>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim deleniti!
</article>
```